# Internal memory representation of LISTS in Perl

Tags: perl, data-structures

How are LISTS internally represented in PERL? 
I had someone telling me it is represented as linked lists, True? If so won't that be a overhead on the interpreter? I'm unable to visualize it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lists in Perl are stored on the stack.  It is an array, resized when necessary, with a second array used to store pointers to demarcate different lists.

If you meant arrays, not lists, Perl arrays consist of a C array of pointers, an allocated size of that array, an offset to the current beginning of the Perl array in the C array, and a used length.

I don't know what you mean by "overhead".  Running programs is an overhead on the interpreter in general :)  But in fact Perl does not use linked lists for arrays or lists.